# call handler on change() of 2 drop down menus

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In asp.net core & razor pages, I have an initial form with 2 drop down menus.  Once each drop down has a selected value, I want to load the rest of the form with a populated model based on what has been selected in both drop downs.

Thinking out loud:

1. Call Handler with ajax() that would load a ViewComponent?
2. Show() the ViewComponent

**What is the best approach to handle this using Razor pages?**

It seems like ViewComponent would be overkill.  Could I just hide a container div with the remaining form fields until ajax() calls the handler and populates the model?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: A partial loaded using AJAX seems sufficient to me: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update

Comment: @MikeBrind would this maintain input values when `ModelState` is invalid?  I'm currently doing it very similar to the article you suggested but lose input values with `[BindProperty]`.  I'm assuming because of the ajax load()

Comment: I'm not sure how the two things are connected. Perhaps you should show some code to illustrate your issue.